# Codename One TextField on Android, no Enter Key

Tags: android, codenameone

I have created a simple form with a TextField.

The TextField has a

```
textField.addActionListener((ActionListener) (ActionEvent evt) -> {
        System.out.println(textField.getText());
    });
```

When I use the simulator I can press enter. However, when I load this on to a Samsung Galaxy Tab the enter button is replaced by :-) and using a USB keyboard doesn't allow my to pressing enter either.

Thanks

Stuart

Comment: The event type being returned from the simulator is evt.getEventType() = Edit

Comment: I have found this happens on other android devices, not just the Samsung. No enter/return key, just a smiley face.

Answer (score 0):

`TextField` defaults to single line whereas `TextArea` defaults to multi-line hence no enter key as a newline isn't supported.

To enable multi-line entry in a `TextField` use `setSingleLineTextArea(false);`.

Comment: Hi Shai

This is not the problem. turning the textfield into multiline does allow you to press enter, however that just moves the text to a new line, the actionlistener is not triggered.

What I need is the textfield to perform a submit action on pressing enter. This works in the simulator but not on a real device

Comment: What you are looking for is probably this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/keyboard-keys-android-pipeline.html

Comment: Thanks Shai, that does sound like an answer, however .putClientProperty looks like it's been removed as a method?